# Laravel 5.5 FormRequest custom error messages validation not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm using the following standard code to validate a form which makes use of various arrays. The rules are correctly implemented, but when using the standard 'messages()' method override, Laravel does not pick up the messages, but simply returns the standard built in messages.

**Output**

```
array (size=7)
  0 => string 'The newitems.0.pickup_date field is required.' (length=45)
  1 => string 'The newitems.0.m_f field is required when newitems.0.item type id is present.' (length=77)
  2 => string 'The newitems.1.pickup_date is not a valid date.' (length=47)
  3 => string 'The newitems.0.size field is required when newitems.0.item type id is present.' (length=78)
  4 => string 'The newitems.1.size field is required when items.1.size unknown is not present.' (length=79)
  5 => string 'The newitems.0.width field is required when newitems.0.item type id is present.' (length=79)
  6 => string 'The newitems.1.width field is required when items.1.width unknown is not present.' (length=81)
```

**FormRequest**

```
UpdateOrderItemsRequest extends FormRequest{

[...]
    public function rules()
    {

        return [
                'items.*.item_type_id' => 'required_with:items.*.m_f,items.*.pickup_date|numeric',
                'items.*.m_f' => 'required_with:items.*.item_type_id',
                'items.*.pickup_date' => 'required_with:items.*.item_type_id|date|nullable',
                'items.*.size' => 'required_without:items.*.size_unknown|numeric',
                'items.*.width' => 'required_without:items.*.width_unknown|numeric',
                'newitems.*.m_f' => 'required_with:newitems.*.item_type_id',
                'newitems.*.pickup_date' => 'required_with:newitems.*.item_type_id|date',
                'newitems.*.size' => 'required_with:newitems.*.item_type_id|required_without:items.*.size_unknown|numeric',
                'newitems.*.width' => 'required_with:newitems.*.item_type_id|required_without:items.*.width_unknown|numeric'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the error messages for the defined validation rules.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {

        return [
            'items.*.item_type_id' => 'An item type is required',
            'items.*.m_f' => 'Gender is required',
            'items.*.pickup_date' => 'A pickup date is required',
            'items.*.size' => 'A size is required',
            'items.*.width' => 'A width is required',
            'newitems.*.m_f' => 'Gender is required',
            'newitems.*.pickup_date' => 'A pickup date is required',
            'newitems.*.size' => 'A size is required',
            'newitems.*.width' => 'A width is required'
        ];
    }
}
```

Is there something dumb and obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The custom validation message attribute must end with validation rule name.
In your case you should use messages function like as follow

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'items.*.item_type_id.required_with' => 'An item type is required',
        'items.*.m_f.required_with' => 'Gender is required',
        'items.*.pickup_date.required_with' => 'A pickup date is required',
        'items.*.size.required_without' => 'A size is required',
        'items.*.width.required_without' => 'A width is required',
        'newitems.*.m_f.required_with' => 'Gender is required',
        'newitems.*.pickup_date.required_with' => 'A pickup date is required',
        'newitems.*.size.required_with' => 'A size is required',
        'newitems.*.width.required_with' => 'A width is required'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I knew it must be something like that. I can see now that I was misreading the documentation.